# What does the function operator %<>% do?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

In an answer to  an R question on  Stackoverflow on how to change the type of a column in a tribble I ran across the following code:

```
mtcars %<>% mutate(as.integer,qsec)
mtcars %<>% mutate(as.integer,[[6]])
```

What does the operator `%<>%` do?  What package do I need to load to use it?

I have googled it but did not find it?

Comment: Type in `?functionname` in your R console and typically you get some help documentation for the function. In this case, [`?%<>%`](https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/reference/compound.html).

Comment: That the answer you found really not mention the package required? Can you provide a link so the answer can be improved?

Comment: @r2evans You need `?"%<>%"` in this case because of the special character. Or `help("%<>%")`

Comment: Right ... emacs/ess doesn't require that, both Rterm and RStudio do. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It is from `magrittr`.  It is called as assignment operator which does update the original object without doing.  It's functionality is similar to the `data.table` `:=` (though this may less efficient compared to data.table as data.table uses pass by reference assignment)

```
mtcars <- mtcars %>% 
     mutate(qsec = as.integer(qsec))
```

i.e. the `%>%` doesn't update the original object.  It just prints the output to the console

```
mtcars %>% 
     mutate(qsec = as.integer(qsec))
```

The class of `qsec` remains the same

```
class(mtcars$qsec)
[1] "numeric"
```

But, if we do the `%<>%`, we don't need to update with `<-`

```
mtcars %<>% 
     mutate(qsec = as.integer(qsec))
class(mtcars$qsec)
[1] "integer"
```